# Update composer dependencies in json file on updating

Tags: composer-php

When I run `composer update`, a lot of dependencies and my composer.json get updated. But, my `composer.json` didn't change, so next time I run `composer install`, I'll get the outdated ones again.

For instance, I have:

```
"require": {
        "symfony/form": "^4.1",
}
```

When I run the command It shows:

> Updating symfony/dotenv (v4.1.4 => v4.1.5): Loading from cache

But the json line stays the same, and `composer install` will install the `4.1.4` version.

Is there a way to update the composer.json file when I run composer update?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can use this tool https://github.com/khanakia/pcu

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You should have a `composer.lock` file after performing `composer update`. You commit this file to version control and then the next person checks out the code can do `composer install` to obtain the correct version.

The `composer.json` file contains the version constraints whereas the `composer.lock` file contains the specific version.

Take a look at the example you had:

```
"require": {
        "symfony/form": "^4.1",
}
```

Here the version constraint for the `symfony/form` package is `^4.1`. This means that it will accept any version 4 build from `4.1`, but not version 5 or higher. So it could obtain version `4.1.1`, or `4.2.13` or anything higher (but below version 5).

https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/versions.md#caret-version-range-

here are the docs on lock files
https://getcomposer.org/doc/02-libraries.md#lock-file

Comment: Thank you! I though that composer.json contained the specific version too